# Await Returns (node:53) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'balance' of undefined when removed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest

How can this be possibly done. I want to be able to do some calculations before I save to MongoDB database.
i am getting this as Error from the Log file

> (node:53) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'balance' of undefined
> Feb 24 11:55:11 AM      at /opt/render/project/src/routes/AccountServices.js:109:49
> Feb 24 11:55:11 AM      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
> Feb 24 11:55:11 AM  (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
> Feb 24 11:55:11 AM  (node:53) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
> Feb 24 11:55:11 AM  (node:53) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

this happens when i remove the await from the function, hence it does not work as I expect.

My code is Looking thus :

```
router.post("/local-transfer", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (
      !req.headers.authorization ||
      !req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ") ||
      !req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
    ) {
      return res.status(422).json({ message: "Please Provide Token!" });
    }

    var account_bank = req.body.account_bank;
    var account_number = req.body.account_number;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var amount = req.body.amount;
    var narration = req.body.narration;
    var currency = req.body.currency;
    var reference = req.body.refernce;
    var debit_currency = req.body.debit_currency;

    url = "https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/transfers";
    fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer FLWSECK_TEST-153740d351951b5f6d5ae8b903e0c467-X",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        account_bank: account_bank,
        account_number: account_number,
        amount: amount,
        narration: narration,
        currency: currency,
        reference: reference,
        debit_currency: debit_currency,
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) =>  {

        const debit = await User.find({ email: email}); //<----------- Adding Await here gives Error
        const debit_balance = parseInt(debit[0].balance);
        const debit_amt = debit_balance - amount;
        await User.findOneAndUpdate({email : email}, {$set: {balance: debit_amt}}); //<----------- Adding Await here gives Error

        const transactions = new Trans({
          email: email,
          narration: narration,
          credit: 0.0,
          debit: amount,
          amount: amount,
        });
        try {
          transactions.save();
          //res.send(savedUser);
          console.log("transaction saved");
        } catch (err) {
          //res.status(400).send(err);
          console.log(err);
        }

        //sendTransferConfirmation(email);
        return res.send({ error: false, data: json, message: "OK" });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        throw err;
      });
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

Adding the await on those two areas return those Errors, I get completely lost Please how do I resolve this?

Tried the Code above and it returns Those Errors.

The Error Looks thus

[image: rgrr.png]

**Edit**

I updated the code to Look like this :

```
router.post("/local-transfer", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (
      !req.headers.authorization ||
      !req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ") ||
      !req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
    ) {
      return res.status(422).json({ message: "Please Provide Token!" });
    }

    var account_bank = req.body.account_bank;
    var account_number = req.body.account_number;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var amount = req.body.amount;
    var narration = req.body.narration;
    var currency = req.body.currency;
    var reference = req.body.refernce;
    var debit_currency = req.body.debit_currency;

    url = "https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/transfers";
    await fetch(url, {  //<---- Added Await fetch here
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer FLWSECK_TEST-153740d351951b5f6d5ae8b903e0c467-X",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        account_bank: account_bank,
        account_number: account_number,
        amount: amount,
        narration: narration,
        currency: currency,
        reference: reference,
        debit_currency: debit_currency,
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(async (json) =>  {

        const debit = User.find({ email: email});
        const debit_balance = parseInt(debit[0].balance); //<-- The error is here
        const debit_amt = debit_balance - amount;
        User.findOneAndUpdate({email : email}, {$set: {balance: debit_amt}});

        const transactions = new Trans({
          email: email,
          narration: narration,
          credit: 0.0,
          debit: amount,
          amount: amount,
        });
        try {
          transactions.save();
          //res.send(savedUser);
          console.log("transaction saved");
        } catch (err) {
          //res.status(400).send(err);
          console.log(err);
        }

        //sendTransferConfirmation(email);
        return res.send({ error: false, data: json, message: "OK" });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        throw err;
      });
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If `debit` is an empty array (`[]`) because none are found, `parseInt(debit[0].balance);` rightfully throws an error.

This error is re-thrown in by the catch handler:

```
      .catch((err) => {
        throw err;
      });
```

Because the `fetch()` call is not `await`-ed, the `try {} catch() {}` doesn't catch that re-thrown error. Change it to this to do so:

```
await fetch(url, {
// ...
```

Of course, rather than just throwing an exception, you might want to add code that checks if `debit.length > 0` and display an appropriate error message to the user.

---

You can test this for yourself. If you remove the `await`, the promise rejection will be [unhandled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#handling_rejected_promises):

```js
window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", function() { 
    console.error("❌ Uncaught error");
});

async function demonstrateWithAwait() {
    try {
        await Promise
            .resolve()
            .then(() => { throw new Error("Example"); })
            .catch((err) => { throw err; })
    } catch (err) {
            console.error("✅ Caught error:", err.message);
    }
}

async function demonstrateWithoutAwait() {
    try {
        Promise
            .resolve()
            .then(() => { throw new Error("Example"); })
            .catch((err) => { throw err; })
    } catch (err) {
            console.error("✅ Caught error:", err.message);
    }
}
demonstrateWithAwait();
demonstrateWithoutAwait();
```

Comment: chaning the await fetch, it returns a new error Cannot read property 'balance' of undefined Let me update source code

Comment: If the result of your query is an empty array, it's only logical that `debit[0].balance` returns an error. You should test if it's empty or not.